# Why numba is performing 100 worse than native python with Tuple of string?

Tags: python, numba

For performance reasons I would like to use [numba](https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) to improve the performance my code. However the numba function has a worse performance than the native python function. Can someone explain me why ?

```
from numba import jit
import timeit

@jit(nopython=True, fastmath=True)
def get_exact_score_with_numba(tokens_to_match, candidate_tokens):
    score = 0.
    for token in tokens_to_match:
        if token in candidate_tokens:
            score += 1.
    return score / len(tokens_to_match)


def get_exact_score_without_numba(tokens_to_match, candidate_tokens):
    score = 0.
    for token in tokens_to_match:
        if token in candidate_tokens:
            score += 1.
    return score / len(tokens_to_match)


tokens_to_match = ('a', 'b')
candidate_tokens = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e')
```

Performance with timeit without numba:

```
>>> number = 200000
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: get_exact_score_without_numba(tokens_to_match, candidate_tokens), number=number)
0.0962326959999995
```

with numba:

```
>>> timeit.timeit(lambda: get_exact_score_with_numba(tokens_to_match, candidate_tokens), number=number)
9.441522490000011
```

so numba is 100 times slower.

Comment: Is it still slower with lists instead of tuples? And did you run it at least once before timing, to make sure the JIT is warm?

Comment: Yes, it is the same performance if I choose tuples or lists but numba does not recommend list because it is a mutable object and list reflection will soon be depreciated see: https://numba.pydata.org/numba-doc/latest/reference/deprecation.html#deprecation-of-reflection-for-list-and-set-types.

Comment: I didn't realize it was scheduled for deprecation, good to know. That said, I've seen decent improvements in code like this by switching to PyPy or using Cython. Furthermore, consider using a set instead of a list/tuple for `candidate_tokens`, or using two sets and taking the length of the set intersection as the score.

Comment: I suspected it would improve if your inputs were NumPy arrays of character sequences instead of strings, but unfortunately not for these inputs. On my machine, your code runs at Numba-35.1us/No-Numba-311ns, while changing the inputs to NumPy arrays beforehand results in Numba-39.4us/No-Numba-9.1us. I guess Numba does *some* optimization because it doesn't take as much of a performance hit as Python, still slower though. Of course, this trend might change with larger inputs.

Comment: Thanks for the trying that idea, indeed with such small inputs it is not worth it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `get_exact_score_without_numba` function takes 0.275 us on my machine which is a **very small time** for a function running in the CPython **interpreter**. An empty Numba function takes at least 0.25 us on my machine because of the cost to switch from CPython to a C code, make some internal checks, etc. Thus, there is no way Numba can be significantly faster on this benchmark.

Beside this, `get_exact_score_with_numba` is still abnormally slow in this case since it takes 25 us on my machine. This overhead comes from Numba itself before calling your compiled function. More specifically, it appears to come from the CPython to Numba internal type conversion (mainly due to strings). **Strings are not yet well supported so far in Numba** (as well as byte arrays). Only an experimental support is provided so far.

Comment: Thanks Jérôme, I will have to optimize other parts of my code then !